# Getting error while using Outer join in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which uses outer join in the substr function. but it gives me an error in that.

```
select * from A, B
where
UPPER(SUBSTR(HOST_NAME(+),1,INSTR(HOST_NAME,'.')-1)) = UPPER(VIRT_HOSTNAME)
```

The above query (equi join) works fine. however, the outer join gives an error as ORA-01417

Can someone help in fixing it?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure it is HOST_NAME(+) not HOST_NAME()?

Comment: select * from A,B
where UPPER(SUBSTR(A.HOST_NAME,1,INSTR(HOST_NAME,'.')-1)) = UPPER(B.VIRT_HOSTNAME)
The above query (equi join) works fine.
however, the outer join gives an error as 
ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table

Comment: @DhanishJose
select * from A,B where UPPER(SUBSTR(A.HOST_NAME,1,INSTR(HOST_NAME,'.')-1)) = UPPER(B.VIRT_HOSTNAME) <br/> The above query (equi join) works fine. however, the outer join gives an error as ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table

Comment: @user3181672 - please provide your table structure with some sample data and expected output. Then I'll provide result query

Comment: Can you include your `OUTER JOIN` query? is it `FULL`,`LEFT` or 'RIGHT` outer join?

Answer (score 0):

The old `(+)` syntax must be used on both instances of the column HOST_NAME.  Or you could use the modern ANSI syntax.

**Problem example**

```
create table a(host_name varchar2(100));
create table b(virt_hostname varchar2(100));

select * from A, B
where UPPER(SUBSTR(a.HOST_NAME(+),1,INSTR(a.HOST_NAME,'.')-1)) = 
  UPPER(b.VIRT_HOSTNAME);

ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table
```

**Solution #1 - use another (+)**

```
select * from A, B
where UPPER(SUBSTR(a.HOST_NAME(+),1,INSTR(a.HOST_NAME(+),'.')-1)) =
  UPPER(b.VIRT_HOSTNAME);
```

**Solution #2 - use ANSI join syntax**

```
select *
from A
left join B
  on UPPER(SUBSTR(a.HOST_NAME,1,INSTR(a.HOST_NAME,'.')-1)) =
    UPPER(b.VIRT_HOSTNAME);
```